# Card spacing issue with animations within a horizontally scrolling div

Tags: css, position, css-animations

I'm trying to display cards within a horizontally scrolling div that animate by continually flipping over and showing both sides. The issue is that for some reason the width of my .storecard classes are not automatically resizing to the size of the image(s) within them, thus causing them to overlap instead of being spread out properly. I believe this spacing issue has something to do with the positioning of the images needing to be 'absolute' in order for the animation to work properly, but I am not sure how to fix it properly without breaking the animation.

Additionally, when I remove all the cards except for one, the card is not horizontally centered like it should be. Again, I believe this has to do with position: absolute on '.back' and '.front'.

I've been working on fixing this all day and am completely stuck.

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/t8vgkba5/1/

Here is a similar JSFiddle that features a horizontally scrolling div with embedded youtube videos in each .card instead of playing cards. The spacing here is correct and what I am aiming for with the playing cards: https://jsfiddle.net/53nytacx/

Thank you!

a snippet of the CSS featured in the JSFiddle:

```
.front {
    margin: 0 auto;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-animation: swag 5s infinite;
    -moz-animation: swag 5s infinite;
    -o-animation: swag 5s infinite;
    animation: swag 5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer it's dynamic now https://jsfiddle.net/p8t1qykL/

I changed the position on ".front"

```
#horizontalcontainer {
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.scrolling-wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.card {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 40px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.card:first-child{
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.scrolling-wrapper {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.back {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-animation: love 5s infinite;
    -moz-animation: love 5s infinite;
    -o-animation: love 5s infinite;
    animation: love 5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    outline: 1px solid transparent; 
}
.front {
    margin: 0 auto;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-animation: swag 5s infinite;
    -moz-animation: swag 5s infinite;
    -o-animation: swag 5s infinite;
    animation: swag 5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: this is very close! instead of the playing cards being a fixed height and width though, i need them to always be 100% height of the .store-scrolling-wrapper class which is set to 50% height of the viewport.

Comment: sort of confused by what u mean gussing something like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/v486c1nt/

Comment: No... the width of the .store-scrolling-wrapper needs to be 100% of the viewport and the height of it needs to be 50%. and then the height of the playing cards within that div need to be exactly 100% of the height of the div. So essentially the height of the playing cards need to always be 50% of the viewport (or 100% of the .store-scrolling-wrapper because the wrapper is set to 50% of the viewport). Does this make sense now?

Comment: i still don't really get it but like could u make a picture if that's not it? coz it's pretty similar to the youtube example

Comment: That has fixed the height issue, thank you! The only remaining issue is that if you delete all but one of the .storecards, the remaining card is not perfectly centered horizontally, it is too far to the right. Do you know why this is happening? If this can be centered perfect, then it is 100% perfect. Here is an image demonstrating the issue: https://ibb.co/nmDhTYF

Comment: its because that was an older version i was testing and i only needed two cards and by centred do u mean on the edge i did that to both sides now it should be what u need

Comment: Not quite, centered as in the same amount of space on the left and the right side of the single card when there is only one. Does that make sense?

Comment: Additionally, I've noticed that when the viewport is portrait, the cards overlap each other, but they shouldn't overlap. In the same sense, if the viewport is very wide, there is additional spacing between the cards that shouldn't be there. There should always be only 40px of space between the cards, regardless of the viewport. Not sure why this is so tricky to set up correctly! I really appreciate your troubleshooting, I've been stuck on these issues for some time.

Comment: since you haven't used CSS grid or some sort of dynamic css layout you'll have to use media queries and do it by eye like the widths of ".storecard" that's one way the other is just make it so the viewport when on smaller devices is 0.5 or something eg "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">"

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help!

Comment: thou there is a way, but ur basically stack 2 objects on top of each other then rotating them so you'll have to find a way to do position absolute without breaking the look its just trial and error just try copying what the youtube example you had and find out what works coz the one i gave you is really close but u just to adjust the widths with media queries

Comment: I really appreciate it! Thank you :)

Comment: This is amazing. You are a genius. Thank you. Have a great weekend!

Comment: hopefully, that helps out with ur card game thingo :)

Comment: Saved my life honestly, again big ups. Thank you :)